# In SQLAlchemy, how do I use the insert().from_select() construct properly?

Tags: python, sql, insert, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a simple function that renders a dict containing (dest_column, src_expression) pairs.

In particular, I'd like the interface to be something like:

```
insert_into(table_obj_a, tbl_object_b, dict(
    col_c = 'col_f',
    col_a = 'col_g',
    col_q = 'col_r + 5',
    col_r = tbl_object_b.col_q,
    col_m = 'rand()',
))
```

In trying to implement this, I've noticed some peculiar behavior with the .from_select functionality, namely that the order of the columns passed to the from_select seems to be ignored.

This is what I'm experiencing:

### bug.py

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

def _insert_into_dict(into_table, from_table, column_dict):
    into_keys = []
    from_vals = []
    for k, v in sorted((k, v) for (k, v) in column_dict.iteritems()):
        into_keys.append(k)
        from_vals.append(v)
    print into_keys
    print from_vals
    sel = sa.select(from_vals, from_obj=from_table)
    print sel
    print
    return into_table.insert().from_select(
        into_keys, sel
    )

md = sa.MetaData()

cols = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'aardvark']

print _insert_into_dict(
    sa.Table('table_a', md, *[sa.Column(x, sa.String) for x in cols]),
    sa.Table('table_b', md),
    dict(
        aaaa='aaaa',
        bbbb='bbbb',
        dddd='dddd',
        eeee='eeee',
        ffff='ffff',
        aardvark='aardvark',
    )
)
```

### Output

```
u@host:~/src/sa_bug$ python bug.py
['aaaa', 'aardvark', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff']
['aaaa', 'aardvark', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff']
SELECT aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff
FROM table_b

INSERT INTO table_a (aaaa, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff, aardvark) SELECT aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff
FROM table_b
```

### Expected

```
u@host:~/src/sa_bug$ python bug.py
['aaaa', 'aardvark', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff']
['aaaa', 'aardvark', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff']
SELECT aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff
FROM table_b

INSERT INTO table_a (aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff) SELECT aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff
FROM table_b
```

As you can see, the order of the column names in the INSERT INTO statement does not match the order of the expressions in the SELECT statement.

Am I misunderstanding the intended use of .from_select() here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zzzeek mentioned, this was a bug in SQLAlchemy < 0.8.4.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2895

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you define your `into_table` like this:

```
sa.Table('table_a', md, *[sa.Column(x, sa.String) for x in cols])
```

The cols list is not sorted, so it is perfectly right that for this list:

```
cols = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'aardvark']
```

the INSERT SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (aaaa, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff, aardvark)
```

Inside your function you are using `sorted()` to sort the `column_dict`, so you must also sort the `cols` list. Just try adding `cols.sort()` after your `cols` definition.

After that the INSERT SQL should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (aaaa, aardvark, bbbb, dddd, eeee, ffff)
```

Comment: But this forces me to know this order in the SELECT statement, which I feel is an error. I could modify _insert_into_dict to introspect the table's column order and modify the select() order, but that seems strange. I'm passing an ordered list into .from_select, but it ignores the order there. The doc even implies that the order of that names parameter is significant: ". The order of columns returned from this FROM clause should correspond to the order of columns sent as the names parameter;" http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select

Comment: Yes this is documented, check this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select, in parameters => select, that means that you should take care of the order.

Comment: No, it says the opposite: "The order of columns returned from this FROM clause should correspond to the order of columns sent as the names parameter;". In other words, that the order I pass into both can be arbitrary as long as the order matches in the names param and the select column param. note that the order of the table's columns is never mentioned, only the order of the SELECT and the order of the names param.

Comment: Let me try some things out, which version of sqla are you running ?

Comment: 0.8.3. I have verified the same behavior on 0.9.0b1 from source

Comment: It seems like it is some sort of internal column ordering issue, these are weird results: https://dpaste.de/S4gx/raw/, i have asked on irc, we will see. I dont really like the "it should" phrase in the docs.

Comment: To update anyone following along at home, it seems the INSERT column order is defined by the Table()'s column order. I still think this an error, either with the docs or the code.

Comment: this issue has been fixed as of http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2895.  The fix is for 0.8.5 and 0.9.0.